# PHP prompt for download ignores new lines

Tags: php, download, newline, prompt

I want the users of my php script to be able to download the contents of a certain text file from my server but I don't want them to download it directly from my server so I want to go through a php file called download.php

I use this code to trigger the file prompt

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=textfile.txt");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize('textfile.txt');

$fp = fopen('textfile.txt', "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

The code works, the file gets downloaded but it seems the code ignores new lines of that text file.

Let's say the content of the original text file is

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
```

The content of the downloaded file would be

```
word1word2word3word4word5
```

How can I fix it that the downloaded file actually retains the new lines of the original text file?

Comment: Are you on a windows host? Open the file with `rb` - the `b` makes it binary mode to prevent PHP from doing EOL-character translations.

Comment: it's a cpanel linux host

Comment: [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) usually works for me, and it's less code...

Comment: Are you loading the textfile into windows notepad or something, then?

Comment: the rb flag didn't help :/, still the same result

Comment: readfile() is disabled for security reasons on the host :(, I'm opening the file with windows editor. If I download the file through FTP Client it perfectly works.

Comment: FTP clients perform newline translations, the above code does not. Try opening in wordpad instead of notepad and you will find it displays correctly. Notepad is basically useless. **EDIT** [Further reading on FTP ASCII vs Binary](http://www.rhinosoft.com/newsletter/NewsL2008-03-18.asp)

Comment: That's true, in Notepad+ it is displayed correctly. The problem with this is that I think most users will open the file in the windows editor anyways and they will find it with no new lines. I got my host to enable readfile() but that didn't help either. Is there a way to translate new lines correctly with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code to convert text file EOLs from Linux, Windows and Mac to Windows.
So no matter what EOLs your file has it will open fine on Win.

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=textfile.txt");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize('textfile.txt'));

$f = file_get_contents('textfile.txt');
$f = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $f); //Convert Windows to Unix
$f = str_replace("\r", "\n", $f); //Convert Mac to Unix
$f = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $f); //Convert Unix to Windows
echo $f;
```

The code is short but it's not too good for huge files.

Comment: Thanks, the code worked out of the box and you told me a lesson about the EOLs :)